# How can I receive data and keep it in binary?

Tags: node.js, binary, buffer, busboy

I'm using the Busboy to parse multipart/form-data in my server, and I want to store each file in a Buffer without automatically convert to utf8. Is it possible?

```
  const result = { files: [] }

  const busboy = new Busboy({
    headers: req.headers
  })

  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    const temp = {}

    file.on('data', (data) => {
      temp.file += data
    })

    file.on('end', () => {
      temp.filename = filename
      temp.contentType = mimetype
      result.files = [...result.files, temp]
    })
  })

  busboy.on('field', (fieldname, value) => {
    result[fieldname] = value
  })

  busboy.on('error', (error) => {
    console.error(error)
  })
```

Currently the `file.on('data')` doesn't work properly, I'm loosing information because the operation `+=` automatically converts the buffer to utf8.

Answer (score 2):

You can set `temp.file` to be an array instead of a string and [`concat the buffer array`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_method_buffer_concat_list_totallength) in the end.

```
  busboy.on('file', (fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) => {
    const temp = {file: []}

    file.on('data', (data) => {
      temp.file.push(data)
    })

    file.on('end', () => {
      temp.file = Buffer.concat(temp.file)
      temp.filename = filename
      temp.contentType = mimetype
      result.files = [...result.files, temp]
    })
  })
```